# SWF file has timer that runs faster in debug player than release player (Adobe Animate, AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash, timer

I have an interactive animation that consists of a button and some lights that are lit in a sequence. The animation also has a timer that shows the passage of time to illustrate the interval between light transitions, so the user knows how much time has passed between each transition in the sequence (it took x amount of time to go from light 'a' to light 'b'). The button controls the speed.

I implemented the timer using the Timer class in AS3:

```
var MyTimer:Timer = new Timer(1);
```

Which means the timer should fire every millisecond.

Now, I am aware the this is nowhere near accurate, due to frame rate (24fps) and the fact that it has to run the code inside the handler function. But I am not going for an accurate timer, in fact I do need it to go slower so the user can see the time between transitions, a scaled/slowed timer if you will. The current time is displayed in a dynamic text field.

As is, when using the debug player in Adobe Animate, the speed of the timer runs at about 1/10th normal speed, taking about 10 seconds to show that a second has passed, which incidentally is great for my purposes. However, this animation will be used in a PDF, in which case, a release player of Flash will be used; and in the release version, the timer appears to be about half as fast, about 1/20th the speed, taking about 20 or more seconds to show that a second has passed.

I'm not sure why this is. How do I get the swf file to be played so that the timer behaves the same in both the debug and release versions of the Flash Player?

I have tried unticking 'Permit debugging' and ticking 'Omit trace statements' (and every combination of un/tick) in the Publish Settings as well as all the Hardware acceleration options.

I've also implemented a FPS counter as suggested here by user 'kglad':

[published swf file is a lot slower than the 'test' mode?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1410718)

But both debug and release versions show the FPS at 23-24.'kglad' gives the last reply in the thread as "the debug players are slower than the non-debug players". I'm not sure what he meant by this as this seems to be the opposite problem that me and the OP of that thread are having, unless s/he meant using the players in a browser.

---

TL;DR

How do I get a timer to behave the same in both the debug and release version of the Flash player?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `Depending on the SWF file's framerate or the runtime environment (available memory and other factors), the runtime may dispatch events at slightly offset intervals. For example, if a SWF file is set to play at 10 frames per second (fps), which is 100 millisecond intervals, but your timer is set to fire an event at 80 milliseconds, the event will be dispatched close to the 100 millisecond interval. Memory-intensive scripts may also offset the events.` [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

Comment: Also: `A delay lower than 20 milliseconds is not recommended. Timer frequency is limited to 60 frames per second, meaning a delay lower than 16.6 milliseconds causes runtime problems.` [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer())

Comment: My advice: don't use `Timer` use `ON_ENTER_FRAME` event and calculate elapsed time with [getTimer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer())

Comment: If you want show that second has passed after about 10s why don't u set timer interval to 10s? simply `new Timer(10000);`

Comment: @Pawel

Because the lights transition every fraction of a second: sometimes a quarter of a second, at other times at half a second or a full second; the pattern varies.

Comment: @DodgerThud
I know the environments are obviously different, I guess I was asking what exactly is different about them so that I can account for them in my code. Also counting frames in both environments yield the same frame rate.

Comment: @DodgerThud

In anycase, I decided to create my own timer class the uses  an ON_ENTER_FRAME event listener and getTimer(). At first the results were exactly the same. I knew I was on the right track when I researched some more and found someone had written something similar:


[openflow-as3 by mathieudesve](https://github.com/mazerte/openflow-as3/blob/master/src/org/papervision3d/core/utils/StopWatch.as)

Comment: What I did was add a Timer.Complete event dispatcher to my class that dispatches a variable amount of times. So when my timer completes, it can dispatch the event 8 - 10 times or however many.

Doing this, I attached a listener function that updated the display of my timer. Along with using a frame rate of 60 fps, this gave me a nice, smooth looking scaled timer that I was looking for.

Thanks again. @DodgerThud